# Program Doesn't Terminate When Requesting an Event from the Particle Cloud

Tags: python, python-requests

The following code attempts to retrieve data from an event in the particle cloud using Python's requests library (particularly get). When I run the code, the program doesn't terminate within a reasonable amount of time (I have waited over 20 minutes). I added print statements to troubleshoot and "hello1" and the url print, but not r.text, so the program seems stuck on the request. What would cause this?

For the sake of this post, I've changed the deviceID, accessToken, and eventName.

```
import requests

deviceId = 'abc123'
accessToken = '345678'
eventName = 'event'
print('hello1')
url = 'https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/' + deviceId + '/events/' + eventName + '?access_token=' + accessToken

print(url)
r = requests.get(url)
print (r.text)
print('hello2')
```